Is there a way to make a long for loop to run faster?
Im making a simple montecarlo simulator that takes in a 3*4 matrix of probabilities, and the number of iterations you want to simulate for. And the output is a table with all the results.
Each row of the table is a list that contains: [iter no, random no, result1, result2]
The logic is simple, just generate a random number and compare it with the cumulative probability. So when i try 1000000 iterations it takes 16 seconds or more and im trying to find out if its possible to get a better time.
So far I've tried:

Using memoization which i guess it doesnt make sense since the return data depends on a random number.
Using numpy arrays and the method cumsum() to get cumulative probabilities.
The best data structured i could come up with is a list of tuples of the possible outcomes and a 2 dimensional list to store the probabilities.

from random import random
import numpy as np

matrix = [
            [0.2, 0.2, 0.05, 0.1],
            [0.7, 0.5, 0.6, 0.4],
            [0.2, 0.25, 0.2, 0.04],
        ]
estados = [
    ("buena", "buena"),
    ("buena", "regular"),
    ("buena", "critica"),
    ("buena", "alta"),
    ("regular", "buena"),
    ("regular", "regular"),
    ("regular", "critica"),
    ("regular", "alta"),
    ("critica", "buena"),
    ("critica", "regular"),
    ("critica", "critica"),
    ("critica", "alta"),
]
estado_siguiente = {"buena": 0, "regular": 1, "critica": 2, "alta": 3}

def get_result(rnd, probabilities, sig_estado=None):
    probabilities= (
        probabilities[0]
        if (sig_estado == "" or sig_estado == "alta")
        else probabilities[estado_siguiente[sig_estado] + 1]
    )

    for i in range(len(probabilities[0])):
        if rnd < probabilities[0][i]:
            return probabilities[1][i]
    return probabilities[1][len(probabilities) - 1]

def start_simulation(probabilities, iter):
    vector_estado = [0, 0, "", "", 0, ""]
    table_final = list()

    #Here i have 4 accumulators for the probabilities of the 3 rows plus one for the whole table because a new result1 depends on the previous result2 meaning sometimes i just need the probs of just a row
    to_np_arr = np.array(probabilities)
    all_acc = (np.cumsum(to_np_arr), estados[:])
    buena_acc = (all_acc[0][0:4], estados[0:4])
    regular_acc = (all_acc[0][4:8], estados[4:8])
    critico_acc = (all_acc[0][8:], estados[8:])

    
    for _ in range(iter):
        rnd1 = random()
        estado1, estado2 = definir_condicion(
            rnd1,
            probabilities=[all_acc, buena_acc, regular_acc, critico_acc],
            sig_estado=vector_estado[3],
        )
        
        #Add the list to the rest of the rows
        tabla_final.append(vector_estado)

        #Here I replace the old list with the new one
        vector_estado = [
            vector_estado[0] + 1,
            "%.3f" % (rnd1),
            estado1,
            estado2,
            "%.3f" % (rnd2) if rnd2 else "-",
            condicion_alta,
        ]
    return tabla_final



It is really hard to help you without a minimal reproducible example (not to mention a code which seems to be written in Spanish). For example definir_condicion is not provided nor the input variable. My guess is that most of the time is spent in overheads but no-one can check that...

If you have a multi-core processor, you can use parallel processing libraries like multiprocessing in Python to distribute the work across multiple cores.
You could also try using a profiling tool to identify the bottlenecks in your code. Python’s cProfile module can help you understand where most of the time is being spent.

I didnt know that, I will do some research and see if i can come up with a solution. Thanks!

Parallel processing works if iterations are independent but operations like vector_estado = [vector_estado[0] + 1, ...] tends to show the opposite. Besides, multiprocessing only worth it if the input data is not too big since inter-process communication and pickling is slow. It is hard to tell whether this is the case or not with the current code though. Profiling is always a good idea.
